# Retrieving the url of an attachement from a sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Guys im using the spquery object to retrieve some items from a list and populate a repeater.  I need to grab the url of the attachment.  Ive set IncludeAttachmentUrls to true but im not sure on the name of the field to use in the repeater.

```
     SPWeb Web = SPContext.Current.Web;
     SPList List = Web.Lists["LinksList"];

     SPQuery Query = new SPQuery();
     Query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
     Query.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true;

     RPTLinks.DataSource = List.GetItems(Query).GetDataTable();
     RPTLinks.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is called `Attachments` but there is an additional operation needed to get the full url for each. Take a look at this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32077/how-do-i-get-the-url-for-attachments-on-an-splistitem-using-c/32080#32080) on SharePoint StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you, it is not a fully functional/tested solution but it might give you a lead:

The foreach loop  and oItem.url is what I use most after a CAML query.

```
     SPList List = Web.Lists["LinksList"];

     SPQuery Query = new SPQuery();
     Query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>"
ArrayList values = new ArrayList();

foreach (SPListItem oItem in oList.GetItems(Query))
{
values.Add(oItem.Url);

// You might need to add extra code here to get the full path if you need to such as spweb url etc..

}
RPTLinks.DataSource = values;

RPTLinks.DataBind();
```